# Bash, Windows 10, and Java - Unknown Command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, java

I'm trying to execute a Java file I was given on Windows 10, inside of the Bash shell.

I open my command prompt. I enter bash.

I set JAVA_CALL="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_192/jre/bin/java"

I try to execute the call, but to no luck.  I read several threads on here and tried several things. I made sure my path includes both the Program Files x86 and the regular Program Files version of my JAVA.

I executed sudo ln -s -f /mnt/c/Program\ Files/Java/jre1.8.0_192/jre/bin/java.exe /bin/java

To try and make a link to it.

I cannot get it to wrong. It always tells me

```
-bash: C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_192/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

When I am certain that file exists. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't crosspost: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54116383/3776858

Answer (score 0):

You need the linux version of the JRE or JDK installed inside your bash subsystem. I think the correct process is basically download the Linux JRE/JDK from Oracle, unpack the files and setup your environment variables pointing at your linux binaries.

Theres a [nice script on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36478741/installing-oracle-jdk-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux) that shows you the steps (if you use this script update the URLs to the latest version - post is from last May):